# iOS App with APNS enabled missing in Notification Center ( for some devices )

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, xcode4.5

We have 5 devices installed with same development version App generated by Xcode > Archive > Distribute > Save for Ad-hoc Distribution > export IPA with an APNS-enabled provisioning profile.

However, only 2 devices have the App in Notification Center, and for the other 3 devices, the item is missing and the 3 devices are unable to receive the push notifications.

What might be the possible reasons behind?

some of them are using iOS 4 & some of them are using iOS 5. I'm using Xcode 4.5 to build & archive the IPA. None of the devices are jailbroken.

Comment: make sure the provisioning profile contain all 5 device ID

Comment: yes. all the devices are contained in the provisioning profile. They can install the Apps, proven that the provisioning profile is working.